# get status of an Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

In my code I write a "Project" object that can contains an Arraylist of "Requirement" objects. I want to write a function that can calculate the status of my Project objects :

1) "Status" can only have 3 values : "todo", "in progress" and "done"

2) If the status of ONE requirement (in the arraylist) is "todo", the final status of the project is "todo".

3) If the status of ALL requirements is "in progress", the status of the project will be "in progress". The same thing for the last status (done).

4) If some requirements have "in progress" status while other have "done" status, the final status of the project will be "in progress". But I don't how can I write this case in the function.

I search a clean way to code this. I'm sure it's easy in Java but I'm newbie in Java and I don't feel comfortable with ArrayList.

I tried this :

```
@Override
public String getStatus(Project project){

    Iterator<Requirement> it = project.listRequirement.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Requirement s = it.next();

        if (s.getStatus()=="TODO")  return "TODO";

    //I don't know how I can write the others lines for the two others status
    }
}
```

Can you help me please to complete my function? Thanks

Comment: What is the expected output for [ `in progress`, `done` ] ?

Comment: What if some projects are in 'in progress' state and there are few which are completed or done.

Comment: As I said, having only status equaling "todo" in my Arraylist is enough to have the status of my project equaling "todo". BUT for "in progress" and "done", it's mandatory to have all the status have the same status. I don't know if it is clear for you?

Comment: @PyThon I forget that. In this case, the status of the progress will be "in progress" (since the entire project is not completly done). But I don't have an idea how to program that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison logic in `if (s.getStatus()=="TODO")` is incorrect as you are using `==` to compare the Strings. You should be using `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead.

You can use a `boolean` to track the statuses. If none of your conditions gets fulfilled then you can return `null` from the function and handle it appropriately in your code.

Here is the corrected snippet:

```
@Override
public String getStatus(Project project) {
    /* Create Final Strings */
    final String TODO = "TODO";
    final String INP = "In Progress";
    final String DONE = "Done";

    /* Boolean Flag */
    boolean flag = false;

    /* Comparison Logic */
    Iterator<Requirement> it = project.listRequirement.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Requirement s = it.next();

        if (TODO.equalsIgnoreCase(s.getStatus())) {
            return TODO;
        } else if (INP.equalsIgnoreCase(s.getStatus())) {
            flag = true;
        }
    }

    /* Return Done */
    if(flag) return INP;
    else return DONE;
}
```

Also, you can use `if-else` or `switch()` to do the comparisons.

Comment: As per the conditions which you stated in your question, if any of the status is `TODO` then your Project Status becomes `TODO` and hence I return `TODO` if I encounter it anywhere while iterating the list. But for the conditions where *All* the statuses needs to be either `In Progress` or `Done` to change the final Project Status you need to iterate the whole list. I store the outcome in a boolean and then later on return the status by doing the boolean comparison. The last line which returns `null` when you have some statuses as `Done` and other as `In Progress` and nothing as `TODO`.

Comment: user2004685 is iterating through each requirment and checking the status (the line `while(it.hasnext()).  If there is a TODO he is immediately returning TODO, per your spec.  He's then setting a boolean array where value zero is 'requirement INP and value 1 is 'requirement done.  He then returns either INP, DONE or NULL depending on whether those aspects are complete or not (the if statement near the bottom)  EDIT:  Beaten by the man himself...

Comment: @salamanka44 *How can you deal with the case of some requirements have "in progress" status while other have "done".* I have modified the last condition. Please check the updated code. It will return `In Progress` if some of the statuses are `In Progress` and some are `Done`.

Comment: @salamanka44 There are a couple of things to improve in this code: 1. Use enum instead of strings. 2. Use two variables with proper names instead of array of booleans. 3. This array is not needed at all - if we find `TODO` we return immediately (as you do), otherwise we need to know whether there is at least one `IN PROGRESS` - if there is, the status of the project is `IN PROGRESS` and if there isn't the status is `DONE`.

Comment: @Jaroslaw Pawlak  can you please propose a code according to your explanation please? Because your explanation is very clear. It's optimal reasoning. Can you just show me please how can I get a function according to that? thanks!!

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Well I have done the modifications after knowing the last condition. As per the latest expectations we do not need the boolean array. I have edited the code.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak I don't understand the reason for down-vote. It is not that using the enums instead of final Strings will change the overall functionality of the code.

Comment: @user2004685 The code is now incorrect. You need a boolean flag (but only one). For input `[IN_PROGRESS, TODO, DONE]` the function should return `TODO` but your current code returns `IN_PROGRESS`. In regards to using enum - it will make code simpler and less error prone. In strings typos are likely to happen and it might be difficult to find, if we use enum it will be a compiler error (or runtime exception when `valueOf` is called)

Comment: @salamanka44 There is no point of adding another answer as it will be effectively the same as this one. Just make `getStatus()` return enum `Status` instead of `String`. Class declaration should look like this: `public enum Status { IN_PROGRESS, TODO, DONE }`. You might want to add `toString()` method or a static method which converts `String` to `Status` - but this is only for the case of legacy code if you couldn't get rid of `String` entirely.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Yes, you are right. One boolean is necessary to track the statuses. Corrected the code. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the List method "contains" to check if a list contains a certain element.

But your logic seems incomplete: What about if the list contains status of both "DONE" and "in progess" (And no "todo")? You never specified what should be returned in that case.

To check if a List only contains status of one type, I would copy the list to a Set (A Collections that doesn't allow duplicates) and then check if that sets size is 1

so maybe something like

```
if(project.listRequirement.contains("TODO")) {
    return "TODO";
} else if(project.listRequirement.contains("INPROGRESS") && new HashSet<String>(project.listRequirement).size()==1) {
    return "INPROGRESS";
} else if(project.listRequirement.contains("DONE") && new HashSet<String>(project.listRequirement).size()==1) {
    return "DONE";
} else {
    // These are the cases your logic doesn't cover yet.....
}
```

Edit:

> @PyThon I forget that. In this case, the status of the progress will be "in progress" (since the entire project is not completly done). But I don't have an idea how to program that...

Okay, so if the list looks like this ("DONE", "DONE", "INPROGRESS") the result is supposed to be "INPROGRESS"?
In that case my edited code from above:

```
if(project.listRequirement.contains("TODO")) {
    // list contains a todo
    return "TODO";
} else if(project.listRequirement.contains("DONE") && new HashSet<String>(project.listRequirement).size()==1) {
    // list contains no todo, and only "done" as only status
    return "DONE";
} else if(project.listRequirement.contains("INPROGRESS")) {
    // list contains no todo, but does contain in progress
    return "INPROGRESS";
} else {
    // this should never happen!
    throw new IllegalStateException();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I forgot this case. I edit my first post to say that in this case, the status of the project will be "in progress". I think that're all the possible cases

Comment: Okay, already edited my answer. Your right that in theory this should cover all cases. Still, sicne your working with a pure list of strings it could be possible that somehow an illegal list gets passed to that method (maybe just a typo). So in that case I think you should just throw a RuntimeException. (I chose IllegalStateException, as the status list is obviously in a state that isn't allowed)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8

```
public static String getStatus(List<Requirement> requirement) {
    if (requirement.stream().anyMatch(r -> r.getStatus().equals("TODO"))) {
        return "TODO";
    } else if (requirement.stream().allMatch(r -> r.getStatus().equals("DONE"))) {
        return "DONE";
    } else {
        return "IN PROGRESS";
    }
}
```

1. If there is any TODO then it is TODO
2. If all are DONE, then it is DONE
3. If there are no TODO and not all are done, then some or all must be IN PROGRESS